# Tunneling Glassfish traffic through a single port

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, tunnel

We are facing the problem that our Java EJB3 client is behind a firewall that allows only outgoing traffic to port 80. The client communicates with a Glassfish server for EJB calls and JMS messages. Therefore we have to somehow direct all traffic (IIOP & JMS) through this one single port. Does anybody know how to do this?

We are using Glassfish 4.1 as a server. I have heard of JProxy but that seems to be inactive by now.

We could theoretically use SSH port forwarding but that would bypass the Glassfish authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Hi from the server's side (even though your problem is the client) you can change the IIOP port either by the admin console or editing your domain.xml .

```
<iiop-service>
            <orb use-thread-pool-ids="thread-pool-1"></orb>
            <iiop-listener address="0.0.0.0" port="3700" lazy-init="true" id="orb-listener-1"></iiop-listener>
            <iiop-listener address="0.0.0.0" port="3820" id="SSL" security-enabled="true">
              <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
            </iiop-listener>
```

The thing is that you need to pass through the IIOP traffic to port 80 and then hit the actual remote server. I think you need to check your options on creating an SSL tunnel, see [here](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

Comment: I updated the question. Your solution solves only part of the problem, we also have JMS traffic that must be directed through that single port 80. And I don't think it is possible to run JMS and IIOP on the same port. Which options for an SSL tunnel do you mean exactly?